# Encoding error using google adwords api

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

I am using the google adwords api. Currenlty my only code is:

```
from googleads import adwords
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
```

This results in an error displaying `Your default encoding, cp1252, is not UTF-8. Please run this script with UTF-8 encoding to avoid errors.`

I am using Python 3.6, which should be UTF-8 by default. What is the source of this error/how is it avoided?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the error? It's difficult to figure out what exactly is going on here.

Comment: @dorian that is all that is displayed. It is a text output to the screen, and does not result in the code crashing (in fact, I've subsequently just ignored the error without any other issues).

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that this is actually a warning emitted by `googleads` whenever the default encoding returned by `locale.getdefaultlocale()` is not UTF-8.

If your script runs without issues, I feel that you can safely ignore it. Otherwise it might be worth a try to set a different locale at the beginning of your code:

```python
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, NEW_LOCALE)
```

I take it that you are running Windows, so I'm not sure what the proper locale definitions are. On Linux, you could use `en_US.UTF-8`, but that's probably not going to work for you.

Comment: This does not work, because locale.setlocale does not change the *default* encoding (at least not on Windows)

Answer (score 3):

Try importing the _locale module.

import _locale

_locale._getdefaultlocale = (lambda *args: ['en_US', 'UTF-8'])